# Error when trying to display ads - Android C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, admob

I am trying to display AdMob ads in my App, but I am getting an error.
I have added Google Play Services, and all my code checks out, I am also using AdMob's own test Ad Id and all the code is from the AdMod guide.
Is there anything I could have missed?

Main Activity Ad Code:

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            //AdMob
            mAdView = (AdView)FindViewById<AdView>(Resource.Id.adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
            mAdView.LoadAd(adRequest);
            //AdMob

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            ActionBar.Hide();
```

Main.axml AdView Code:

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
          xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:id="@+id/adView"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          ads:adSize="BANNER"
          ads:adUnitId="HERE_MY_UNIT_ID">
  </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Error Message:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the order. Your `mAdView` object is Null because you hadn't indicated the contentView of the Activity.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        ActionBar.Hide();

        //AdMob
        mAdView = (AdView)FindViewById<AdView>(Resource.Id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        mAdView.LoadAd(adRequest);
        //AdMob
}
```

Comment: Change the order of what sorry?

Comment: Set the activity contentView then initialize your Admod view. See the code I added of the `OnCreate` method. Compare it with yours.